# Animate status bar alongside custom transition in segue

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, statusbar

I have two `ViewControllers`, using a custom segue from the first I present the second, with custom animator and a percent based interactor.

I want to slide up the status bar alongside the controller transition.

In the second `ViewController` I have this in order to hide the status bar

```swift
override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return .slide
    }

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
```

I know I should call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` in an animation block in order to animate it, and use `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` method [animateAlongsideTransition:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioncoordinator/1619300-animatealongsidetransition?language=objc) in order to make it follow the transition, but I am not sure where should I call this method.

I tried in the `viewWillAppear` method of the second controller but it still disappeared immediately without animation.

What is the right place to call this?

Comment: might you post the code you are using for: `animate(alongsideTransition` ?

Comment: That's the issue, I know I should use some variation of that but am not sure how to use it.

Comment: I see, consider that once the `slide` animation starts, there is no way to stop/tune it.

Comment: So the only way is to let it happen and not control it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you couldn't see the animation is because in your second view controller you always return `true` to `prefersStatusBarHidden`, then such view controller starts with that condition, hence doesn't have any "chance" for playing the animation.

So in the second view controller you might try doing so:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
  override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation { get { return .slide } }
  override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return statusBarHidden }
  var statusBarHidden = false

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.statusBarHidden = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) {
      self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
  }
}
```

Moreover in your `Info.plist` be sure to have `View controller-based status bar appearance`= `YES`

Comment: Unfortunately this will not sync the animation with my transition

Comment: May I ask you why you need `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` ?

Comment: I want the animation of the status bar to happen alongside the segue transition, and I can't just set the time to be the same since I have an interactor and can drag the transition with the gesture.

Comment: this worked for me although I set the animation + setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() in viewWillAppear. It's a very good answer!